# Error Handling in Mulesoft 4 not working as expected

Tags: exception, error-handling, mulesoft

I am having trouble bubbling up a custom error from my SYS Api( try( insert into db) –> ON ERROR PROPAGATE —> RAISE ERROR(Original error - DB:Connectivity) and (customer Error - APPCust:DBConnectivity)) from my Sys API to Process API. I am supposed to do remediation in Process API if I encounter this error (APPCust:DBConnectivity) .Unfortunately doesn’t look like this custom error bubbles up to the process api and it gets converted to default error (HTTP:INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR) which I am not expecting as I need to catch specific error that was raised in my Sys API and then perform action based on this specific custom error.

BTW I am not even able to catch the DB:Connectivity original error. I believe the exception should bubble up accurately which is not happening here.

Answer (score 0):

On Error Propagate means to continue to use default error handling which actually and eventually leads to this HTTP:INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR and error 500.

To take control use On Error Continue - it will catch the error, do whatever you define in the error handling area and finish this particular flow with these results.

It is better to catch errors/exceptions as close to origin as possible. When you dael with them on API (APIKit) level it is already too late. As you described db error became http error.

Deal with error handling on each flow separately. It is easy to fix individual issues than deal with errors in general. Upper level is designed to catch and deal with error which you do not know about or hard or unnecessary to work with. Easily predicted exceptions should be handled immediately.

Look here for simple example https://simpleflatservice.com/mule4/OnErrorContinue.html